# Perl: Specifying occurrences in substitution regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to substitute all instance of a comma or a hyphen in the string `$charlie`. Here is the code I initially tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $charlie = "Charlie, 59, 2009";
print "Old Charlie: $charlie\n";
$charlie =~ s/[\,-]/ /;
print "New Charlie: $charlie\n";
```

This produces the output:

```
C:\scripts\perl\sandbox>charlie_substitute.pl
Old Charlie: Charlie, 59, 2009
New Charlie: Charlie  59, 2009
```

As you can tell, only the first comma was replaced by a space. In an attempt to account for multiple commas, I changed the regex to `$charlie =~ s/[\,-]{1,2}/ /;` but I still get the same output.

How would I correctly specify the number of occurrences to look for in a substitution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `/g` to replace "globally".

```
$charlie =~ s/[,\-]/ /g;
                      ^
                      |
```

(`,` isn't special in character classes or even in regex in general, so it doesn't need escaping. On the other, `-` can be special in character classes. If anything should be escaped, it's `-`. That said, `-` doesn't need to be escaped if it's the first or last character of the class as it is here.)